# Mac File Upload Dialog Disables Allowed Files

Tags: macos, safari, web-app

So a few of my mac users are having an issue where when using Mac Safari or Chrome (latest versions) when they try to use our upload features then in some cases allowed files such as pdf, xls, png, etc display as gray and are disabled not allowing them to upload.

When I try to reproduce this issue on a tester Mac with the same versions and everything I can not reproduce the issue and everything works as expected.

My question is; is there some setting or something they might need to check/uncheck that could be the culprit as to why on their macs they are getting these files grayed out and disabled in the file upload dialogs from the browsers? I'm not a mac guy so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1589471/mac-file-upload-dialog-disables-allowed-files

Comment: @Tetsujin fair enough I'll delete the other one since so far it's been useless.....

Comment: Thanks. You can always flag a mod for help if a question is dead in the water or need help migrating it. Any chance you have a screen image you can share or a public endpoint we can test to pick apart how the upload code is engineered?